# My short riddle 1

Tags: riddle, word

I am something. Take away a letter and I'm still such a thing. Take away another and I'm still such a thing. Take away another and I cease being such a thing. What am I now?

Hint 1:

> I wasn't a word initially.

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit (rev 4) because a) people who saw the hint have an unfair advantage and b) 'Were you actually expecting to find a hint? Ha ha ha!' is not constructive in any way.

Comment: Now it's getting broad I guess.

Comment: This puzzle cannot be accurately solved without the hint. Even then, there is nothing that suggests one answer is more correct than another.

Answer (score 19):

This fits

> **I am something. Take away a letter and I'm still one.**
>
> Alone ->Lone
>
> **Take away another and I'm still one**
>
> Lone->One
>
> **Take away another and I cease being one.**
>
> One->on
>
>  So you're now the word *on.*

Explanation

> The initial something is the word *alone*. 
>
>  *(The 'still' in the next phrase indicates you were one/singular earlier too.)*
>
>  Taking away the letter *a*, you're now the word *lone*, which essentially signifies singularity.
>
>  Taking away the letter *l*, you're now the word *one*.
>
>  Taking away the letter *e*, you're now the word *on*, and no longer *one*.

Comment: how does the hint fits here ?

Comment: Doesn't. But every question should be designed so it can be answered without a hint. And without the hint, this fits.

Comment: That's not what was intended. Good answer though.

Answer (score 8):

Is it:

> **Postman with 3 letters to deliver?**

Because:

> Take one letter, take 2 - he still has a letter to deliver. Take away third, and he isn't a postman with letters anymore.

Comment: Wait, you said it's correct and then you said it's not correct? Which is it?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure. But I think, you were (Updated after hint)

> A **Noun** or **Xoun** (Taking any letter as the first which doesn't give a word $\rightarrow$ as per hint)

I am something.

> **NOUN** *is* something. It's a word and is used to define class of things.
>  Also, **XOUN** is gibberish. And gibberish is something.

Take away a letter and I'm still one.

> <s>N</s>oun $\rightarrow$ **Uno** $\rightarrow$ One in *Italian*
>  <s>X</s>oun $\rightarrow$ **Uno** $\rightarrow$ One in *Italian*

Take away another and I'm still one

> Un<s>o</s> $\rightarrow$ **UN** $\rightarrow$ One in *French*

Take away another and I cease being one

> Un **$\rightarrow$** U/N stops being one. And, now you are just a letter U or N. :-)

Comment: Uno is also Spanish for 1 ;)

Answer (score 5):

A very long shot !

> You are nothing
> Initially you were a phase "is a"
>  Take away a letter "a", "is" refers to singular
>  Take away another letter "s", "I" refers to singular
>  Take away another letter "i", you are now Nothing

Answer (score 5):

You are a

> bee

take a letter away

> be

and another

> b

and another

> 

Comment: This was my first thought, too... until the hint, of course.

Comment: @SenorAmor a bee isn't a word ... it is an insect. 'be' *is* just a word on the other hand ;)

Comment: To bee or not to bee?

Answer (score 2):

You are

> IIII

Based on the hint, you aren't a word initially.

> Take away any letter, you get III. Take away any other letter, you get II. Take away a third letter, and you get I. You have transitioned from nonsense to nonsense to nonsense to a word.

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> Sword (something that causes pain)

Take away one letter

> Word (Can also cause pain)

Take away another letter

> Ord (Old English for spear point) (Can also cause pain)

Take away another letter

> Rd which means nothing

The hint:

> The "such a thing" refers to something that inflicts pain.  It initially wasn't a WORD but a SWORD (This may be a stretch)

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Postman

Explanation:

> Based on answer by @Zizy, "Postman with letters" was almost correct. The question asks "what am I now" - now I am a "postman without letters" or just postman. But if this is correct, I think Zizy's answer should really get the points.